# Prevent jquery mobile panel from opening?

Tags: events, jquery-mobile, panel

I have the following code. As You can see I have tried most of the common methods for preventing it from opening.

I'm doing this because in the panelbeforeopen I would like to check to see if the user is logged in and then only show the panel if they are.

```
$(document).on('panelbeforeopen', '#right_panel', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        alert('test');
        return false;
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I had to bind an event handler to the button that was responsible for opening the panel.

One note is that the code that will link an a tag automatically to a panel sets up its event handler as a click event not a tap event. It also for what ever reason will not work if you use .on to bind your click event handler. You must bind it like normal.

See [js fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/FYYvG/1/)

```
$('.footer .right_panel').on('click', function (event) {        
    alert('test');
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```